# How to prove a process is a forward process base on the time independence of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems

I met a problem in stochastic calculus assignment, which writes:

Suppose $\vec{y}(t), \vec{x}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are two vectors. A backward process for the nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is defined as a process $\vec{x}(t)$ satisfying $\frac{d}{dx}\vec{x}(t)=A\vec{x}(t)$. Suppose $<\vec{y}(t), \vec{x}(t)>$ is independent of time $t$ for any backward process $\vec{x}(t)$, show that $\vec{y}(t)$ is a forward process in the sense that $\frac{d}{dx}\vec{y}(t)=A^*\vec{y}(t)$ where $A^*$ is $A$'s adjoint. $<>$ denotes some inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let's assume all vectors are column vectors. What I thought is, let $G$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix for the inner product. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}<\vec{y}(t), \vec{x}(t)> = (\frac{d}{dt}\vec{y}^T(t))G\vec{x}(t) + \vec{y}^T(t)G\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x}(t)= <\frac{d}{dt}\vec{y}^T(t),\vec{x}(t)> + <\vec{y}^T(t),\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x}(t)> = 0
$$
We also have 
\begin{align*}
<\frac{d}{dt}\vec{y}^T(t),\vec{x}(t)> + <\vec{y}^T(t),\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x}(t)> &= <\frac{d}{dt}\vec{y}^T(t),\vec{x}(t)> + <\vec{y}^T(t),A\vec{x}(t)> \\
&= <\frac{d}{dt}\vec{y}^T(t),\vec{x}(t)> + <A^*\vec{y}^T(t),\vec{x}(t)>
\end{align*}
Does it suggest that $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{y}(t) + A^*\vec{y}(t)=0$? Am I wrong somewhere?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: As you noticed you do need a minus sign: it should be $y'=-A^*y$.

Comment: @JohnB Yes exactly. But where does it come from then? I might have made some silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: Simply the statement of your exercise is incorrect. Note that this is a standard observation: see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083209/adjoint-differential-equations

Comment: @JohnB I see what you mean. Thank you!